# Dynamically created LinkButton won't go into command event

Tags: c#, command, linkbutton, dynamically-generated, commandargument

I've asked this before, but sadly I'm still having issues and the issue wasn't resolved. Basically, I'm dynamically creating a LinkButton for each row of a table I am generating, and that button has the task of deleting the row with the corresponding ID from the database. To do this, I seemingly need to assign the LinkButton a Command so it'll go into the event when it is clicked. Problem is, when the button's clicked the program *never* goes into the command - I've put breakpoints in there and it never goes into them. Here's my code:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
            {

                ColorConverter conv = new ColorConverter();
                string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TPRTestConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                TPRDBDataContext dc = new TPRDBDataContext();
                DataContext db = new DataContext(connection);
                Table<SageAccount> SageAccount = db.GetTable<SageAccount>();
                Table<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItem = db.GetTable<InvoiceItem>();
                Table<Invoice> Invoice = db.GetTable<Invoice>();
                Boolean alloweditting = (from s in dc.Invoices where s.id.ToString() == Request.QueryString["id"] select s.alloweditting).Single();
                if (alloweditting == false)
                {
                    dtlsInsert.Visible = false;
                    modalPanel.Visible = false;
                }
                int sagepk = (from s in dc.Invoices where s.id.ToString() == Request.QueryString["id"] select s.sageaccount).Single();
                lblSageID.Text = (from s in dc.SageAccounts where s.ID == sagepk select s.SageID).Single();
                lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();


                Table table = new Table();
                table.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
                table.GridLines = (GridLines)3;

                TableHeaderRow header = new TableHeaderRow();
                header.BackColor = (System.Drawing.Color)conv.ConvertFromString("#EDEDED");
                foreach (string header2 in new string[] { "", "Quantity", "Rate", "Description", "Nominal Code", "Subtotal" })
                {
                    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                    cell.Text = header2;
                    header.Cells.Add(cell);
                }

                table.Rows.Add(header);

                var data = (from s in dc.InvoiceItems where s.invoiceid.ToString() == Request.QueryString["id"].ToString() select s);
                foreach (var x in data)
                {

                    TableRow row = new TableRow();
                    if (x.invoicetext == null)
                    {
                        decimal total;
                        try
                        {
                            total = (decimal)x.rate * (decimal)x.quantity;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            total = 0;
                        }
                        int i = 0;
                        foreach (string columnData in new string[] { x.id.ToString(), x.quantity.ToString(), x.rate.ToString(), x.description, x.nominalcode, total.ToString("N2") })
                        {
                            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                            {
                                if (i == 0)
                                {
                                    LinkButton lnkdel = new LinkButton();
                                    lnkdel.Text = "Delete";
                                    lnkdel.ID = "lnkDel" + Guid.NewGuid();

                                    if (alloweditting == false)
                                    {
                                        lnkdel.Enabled = false;
                                    }
                                    lnkdel.Font.Bold = false;
                                    lnkdel.CommandArgument = x.id.ToString();
                                    //lnkdel.Command += lnkdel_Command;
                                    //lnkdel.Command += new CommandEventHandler(this.lnkdel);
                                    cell.Controls.Add(lnkdel);
                                    i++;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    cell.Text = columnData;
                                }


                            }

                            row.Cells.Add(cell);
                        }



                        runningtotal = runningtotal + total;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int i = 0;

                        foreach (string columnData in new string[] { x.id.ToString(), x.invoicetext })
                        {
                            TableCell cell = new TableCell();

                            if (i == 0)
                            {
                                LinkButton lnkdel = new LinkButton();
                                lnkdel.Text = "Delete";
                                lnkdel.ID = "lnkDel" + Guid.NewGuid();

                                if (alloweditting == false)
                                {
                                    lnkdel.Enabled = false;
                                }
                                lnkdel.Font.Bold = false;
                                          //lnkdel.Command += lnkdel_Command;
                                    //lnkdel.Command += new CommandEventHandler(this.lnkdel);
                                lnkdel.CommandArgument = x.id.ToString();



                                cell.Controls.Add(lnkdel);
                                i++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                cell.Text = columnData;
                                cell.ColumnSpan = 5;
                            }
                            row.Cells.Add(cell);

                        }

                    }

                    switch (x.formatoptions)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            row.ForeColor = (System.Drawing.Color)conv.ConvertFromString("black");
                            row.Font.Bold = false;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            row.ForeColor = (System.Drawing.Color)conv.ConvertFromString("black");
                            row.Font.Bold = true;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            row.ForeColor = (System.Drawing.Color)conv.ConvertFromString("red");
                            row.Font.Bold = false;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            row.ForeColor = (System.Drawing.Color)conv.ConvertFromString("red");
                            row.Font.Bold = true;
                            break;
                    }
                    table.Rows.Add(row);
                }

                TableFooterRow row2 = new TableFooterRow();
                TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
                cell2.Text = "<span style\"text-align: right; width: 100%;\">Total = <b>" + runningtotal.ToString("N2") + "</b></span>";
                cell2.ColumnSpan = 6;
                row2.Cells.Add(cell2);
                table.Rows.Add(row2);

                var update = (from s in dc.Invoices where s.id.ToString() == Request.QueryString["id"] select s).Single();
                update.total = runningtotal;

                dc.SubmitChanges();
                datatable.Controls.Clear();
                datatable.Controls.Add(table);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("Invoices.aspx");
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



        }


        protected void lnkdel_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TPRTestConnectionString"].ConnectionString;


            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM InvoiceItem WHERE id = @id", conn);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                conn.Open();
                try
                {
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write(ex);
                }
            }
    }
```

Note I've commented out 2 of the crucial lines for posting here, just to point out that I've tried both of the lines that's commented out, and neither work :(

Comment: This is one way to solve this dynamic attached events issue.  there are others, you have to understand the page life cycle to make this stuff work, google `asp.net page life cycle` to learn more or read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141169/c-dynamically-created-linkbutton-command-event-handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the controls on *every* postback.  You appear to be only creating them on the initial get (that query string check).   On the post back, those controls never get recreated so no event fires.

It's notoriously counter-intuitive, but while ASP.NET bends over backwards to make you think that the instance of your page class is the same between two HTTP requests, the reality is that they are not the same.  A new instance is created each time.   It looks like you are trying to avoid adding the dynamically generated controls multiple times -- thinking you don't want duplicates.  The reality is that you will *never* get duplicates when adding dynamically generated controls in a life-cycle method such as `OnInit()` since it's always a new instance of the page class, and thus those dynamically generated controls are gone.

The reason this is usually transparent to developers is that all the controls in the code-front are automatically re-generated for you on both the initial request and every single post-back.  For your dynamically created controls, you happen to have this line:

```
if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null) { ... }
```

Unless you're doing something special, that "id" attribute will not be in the query string on the postback.  This means that none of the code in the `if` block will be run on the post back (when your event actually fires.)  This means that your `if`-check at the top should be removed altogether.  *All* that code should run for each and every request (GET *and* POST).

Comment: Hmm, so basically above all the if statements in the Page_Init method, to initialise the table? What about the link button, seeing as they're all dynamically generated for each row?

Comment: Cheers buddy, in the case of the user accessing the page without the query string, wouldn't the page error though as a lot of my code references the query string? Although I guess I could encase it in a try/catch, but would I end up being in the exact same situation if so?

Comment: @Chris, right, so you need to store that id somewhere so it's available on postback.  One way is by using a hidden field.  Another way is to use the ViewState property:  `ViewState["id"] = Request["id"];`  Oh, and if you mean that it's actually acceptable to access the page without the "id" at *all* then you need to be more sophisticated -- Change your `if` statement to check for an id in *either* the query string or, for example, the `ViewState`.

Answer (score 0):

Just saying I've created a workaround - simply creating a simple  link to the page, along with a query string containing the id of the row to delete