# Event handler command is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

This is so weird for me... in the program i have a link button generated on a search query, on click of this link button will redirect to another page... thats were its not working any ideas?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //TextBox1.Text = (string)Session["keys"];
    string s = TextBox1.Text;
    string[] words = s.Split(' ');
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select fname from uploads where fname like '" + '%' + words[i] + '%' + "'", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                string z = ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]["fname"].ToString();

                // creation of linkbutton
                LinkButton linkbtn = new LinkButton();
                linkbtn.Text = z + "<br><br>";
                linkbtn.Visible = true;
                linkbtn.CommandName = z;
                linkbtn.Command += new CommandEventHandler(this.Link1_Click);
                linkbtn.ID = h.ToString();
                this.Panel3.Controls.Add(linkbtn);
                h++;
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
protected void Link1_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    startdownload(e.CommandName);

}
protected void startdownload(string s)
{
    Response.Redirect("Downloading.aspx");
}
```

Comment: This is web forms code not MVC. Please re-tag.

Comment: have any idea that could help me?

Comment: There is a serious sql injection vulnerability here, parametrize your inputs

Comment: This is the exact problem described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/201301/701062. You need to re-add the controls during or before `PageLoad` in order for the post-back event to fire.

Comment: What's your concrete problem? Did you debug this code? Do you reach the startdownload-method? Is just the redirect itself not working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Dynamically created LinkButton Command Event Handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141169/c-sharp-dynamically-created-linkbutton-command-event-handler)

Comment: @khlr nope i didn't reach the startdownload method? con you help

Comment: @Gary.S add your answer so that i can accept (detailed) please???

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-add the controls during or before `PageLoad` in order for the post-back event to fire.